# Call web service with parameters

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I have to call a web service.
The web service has input two parameters and does not return anything in output.

Can you tell me if the code (written below) is correct and complete?
I inserted it inside the main.

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pwd", "domain");

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{
    string json = "{p1:\'Hello\'";

    string tmpjs = ",p2:\'world\'}";                       
    json = json + tmpjs;

    streamWriter.Write(json);
    streamWriter.Flush();
    streamWriter.Close();
}

HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse) httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: indentation is a bit off. reason for using tmpjs is unclear. streamwriter does not need to be closed when it is in `using`. if it compiles without error, run it and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier for to [Add service reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) and call your Web Service Methods.

Then you can access the service like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/step-3-accessing-the-web-service).

Your code would look like this:

```
string json = "{p1:\'Hello\'";                              

string tmpjs = ",p2:\'world\'}";   
json = json + tmpjs;

using(YourService service = new YourService()) 
{
    service.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pwd", "domain");
    serivce.YourServiceMethod(json, param2);
}
```